# concat LPCTSTR strings

Tags: c++, filepath, concatenation

1. I have created an md5 hasher which takes a file and returns the hash value.
2. I have used "hFind = FindFirstFile(dir, &data)" to list the files of a directory.
3. In order to pass the path of these files to my hash function i need to concat the FILE NAME to the FILL PATH (both are LPCTSTR).

My FileHashComputing Snippet =
[computing hashValue of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157155/compute-hash-of-the-listed-files)

code snippet:

```
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
LPCTSTR dir = L"c:\\*.*";
LPCTSTR FNAME;
LPCTSTR FULLPATH = L"c:\\";

hFind = FindFirstFile(dir, &data);
FindNextFile(hFind, &data);
printf("%ws\n", data.cFileName);

FNAME = data.cFileName;
printf("%ws\n", FNAME);
```

Comment: Just using `LPCWSTR` would be easier than `LPCTSTR` and would allow `(std::wstring(FILEPATH) + FILENAME).c_str()` to be passed into a function (but I'd recommend storing `std::wstring`s instead and doing the `c_str()` when you need to pass it into a function).

Comment: didn work ... just printing the initial path without the file name

Comment: I've never seen `%ws` before.  What compiler are you using?  It doesn't appear to be part of any standard that I can find on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LPCTSTRs are just pointers. It is meaningless to concatenate them. To concatenate two strings you need some memory to contain the result, but you have not allocated any memory for that. To work with strings without the hassles of dealing with pointers and buffers use the std::wstring class.

```
#include <string>

std::wstring full(L"C:\\");
full += data.cFileName;
wprintf(L"%ws\n", full.c_str());
```

Comment: I've never seen `%ws` before.  What compiler are you using?  It doesn't appear to be part of any standard that I can find on the web.